# $O$ is dedekind domain and $K=Frac(O)$. Suppose $a\in L$ where $L/K$ is finite separable extension. If $Tr(a), Norm(a)\in O$, is $a\in O_L$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

$O$ is dedekind domain and $K=Frac(O)$. Suppose $a\in L$ where $L/K$ is finite separable extension.

$\textbf{Q:}$ If $Tr(a), Norm(a)\in O$, is $a\in O_L$ where $O_L$ is integral closure of $O$ in $L$? I knew this holds for $K$ complete/$O$ complete as polynomial ring valuation is induced by the valuation on irreducible polynomial. If $f=\sum_ia_ix^i$ with $f$ irreducible, then $v(f)=\min\{v(a_0),v(a_n)\}$. It seems that the statement is true as I can use local statement for each valuation. Completion is flat. So I do not change any inherent information as $Tr$ and $Norm$ decompose into local sums or local products.

Comment: Think about $K=\mathbb Q$, $L=K(a)$, $a$ a root of $x^3+x/2+1$

Comment: @user8268 Indeed. So trace and norm alone are not sufficient to determine integrality. I was thinking that norm should somehow give me all information of the denominators of the $a$'s roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false, consider a root $\alpha$ of an irreducible cubic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the form
$$
x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c
$$

Then the norm of $\alpha$ is $-c$ and the trace is $-a$, but $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer if and only if $b$ is an integer.